# Othographic Projection in XTK

Tags: xtk, orthographic, 3d-rendering

So I am using XTK to develop a app that will allow users to view multiple 3D meshes in one renderer. The problem is that it uses a perspective camera instead of a orthographic, which causes panning to 'rotate' the meshes a bit. Has anyone been successful in getting XTK to render orthographically without modifying source code? I would rather not modify it but if I have to I will. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can see, there's no way to set a 3D camera to be in orthographic perspective without modifying the source code. However, it seems fairly straight forward to add that functionality. If you add the following in a function to camera3D.js, that should get the right result (I tested it on [XTK Tutorial 00](http://lessons.goxtk.com/00/)).

```
this._perspective = X.matrix.makeOrtho(X.matrix.identity(), -100, 100, -100, 100, 1, 10000);
```

It uses [goog.vec.Mat4.makeOrtho](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git-history/f104d65e5b33df6e4177913b3a6418844d37222e/local_closure_goog_vec_mat4.js.source.html#line1328)